# Xunit testing for Xamarin.Forms MVVMLight app is not working properly and never stops running

Tags: unit-testing, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm-light, xunit

I'm learning to write unit test cases for Xamarin apps. I have a very basic forms app created using MVVMLight and ServiceLocator. I have a login page and a LoginViewModel which I want to test. I've created a Xunit test project for testing LoginViewModel. Firstly, I created a passing test(Fact) that checks the test project is working or not. It runs fine and passes smoothly.

After that, I wrote another theory with InlineData to test my login command's functionality and there the blunder happens and the test written for login command never stops running and doesn't passes or fails the test.

I'm mentioning both my classes below, if any one can take a look and tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
 public class LoginViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="T:MVVMArchitecture.ViewModels.LoginViewModel"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="navigation"> Navigation </param>
    /// <param name="dialog"> Dialog</param>
    public LoginViewModel(INavigationService navigation, IDialogService dialog) : base(navigation, dialog)
    {
        Title = PageTitles.LoginTitle;
        Validator = new UserValidator();
        ValidationContext = new ValidationContext<User>(User, new PropertyChain(), new RulesetValidatorSelector(new[] { "Login", "Password" }));
    }

    #region Properties
    User user = new User();

    public User User
    {
        get => user;
        set { SetProperty(ref user, value); }
    }

    RelayCommand loginCommand;

    public RelayCommand LoginCommand
    {
        get => loginCommand ?? (loginCommand = new RelayCommand(LoginUser, () => !IsBusy));
    }

    #endregion

    #region Action Hanlders
    async void LoginUser()
    {
        if (IsBusy)
            return;
        IsBusy = true;
        LoginCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();

        var validationResults = Validator.Validate(ValidationContext);
        if (validationResults.IsValid)
        {
            var loggedIn = await LoginFlow();
            if (loggedIn)
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    var navPage = new NavigationPage(new HomePage())
                    {
                        BarBackgroundColor = (Color)Application.Current.Resources["AppThemeColor"],
                        BarTextColor = Color.White
                    };
                    App.ConfigureMainPage(navPage);
                });
            }
            else
            {
                IsBusy = false;
                await DialogService.ShowMessage(AuthenticationAlerts.InvalidCredentials, AuthenticationAlerts.LoginFailed);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            IsBusy = false;
            await DialogService.ShowMessage(validationResults.Errors[0].ErrorMessage, AuthenticationAlerts.LoginFailed);
        }

        IsBusy = false;
        LoginCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Login flow to login user based on internet and service mode.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The flow.</returns>
    async Task<bool> LoginFlow()
    {
        return await Task.Run(async () => CommonUtils.Instance.IsConnected ? await ServiceManager.Instance.LoginUser(User) : await DataManager.Instance.LoginUser(User));
    }

    #endregion

    // sample method call from code behind
    public void DisplayData(string msg)
    {
        DialogService?.ShowMessageBox(msg, AppConstants.LoginPage);
    }
}
```

And my test class:

```
public class UnitTest1
{
    App app;
    LoginViewModel loginViewModel;

    public UnitTest1()
    {
        Models.TestingMocks.Init();
        app = new App();
        loginViewModel = new LoginViewModel(ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<INavigationService>(),
            ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IDialogService>());
    }

    [Fact]
    public void MustPass()
    {
        int expected = 1;
        int actual = 1;
        Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
        Assert.NotNull(app);
        Assert.NotNull(loginViewModel);
    }

    [Theory]
    [InlineData("ACosta", "Time2Eat!")]
    public void EmptyUsernamePassword(string username, string password)
    {
        var model = CreateViewModelAndLogin(username, password);
        //var v = ServiceManager.Instance.LoginUser(model.User);
        //A.CallTo(() => v.Result).MustHaveHappened();
        Assert.NotNull(model);
    }

    private LoginViewModel CreateViewModelAndLogin(string userName, string password)
    {
        loginViewModel.User = new User
        {
            UserName = userName,
            Password = password
        };

        loginViewModel.LoginCommand.Execute(null);

        return loginViewModel;
    }

}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Why using `async void`? (note `async void` works best with async event handlers)

Comment: This looks more like an integration test than an isolated unit-test based on the tightly coupled design of the view model and what would be access when testing.

Comment: @Nkosi how can I make it loosely coupled or unit test instead of integration test?

Comment: I used MVVMLight to make the app loosely coupled instead, but I'm new to it.

Comment: Extract login flow out into its own concern/service. Also extract platform concerns (ie Device.*) out into its own concern/service. Explicitly inject extracted concerns into view model. Refactor command to use async event handler instead of plain async void method.

Comment: @Nkosi can you provide me a sample code for above to show what exactly do you meant and want me to do? It will be of great help. Thanks in advance!